# Why won't my counting thread work properly when using pthreads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, pthreads

In my `main()` function, I call `pthread_create` to create a new thread. I pass into it the name of a text file, and the thread opens the text file, counts the number of lines and then returns that number to `main()` where I set an integer `totalCount +=` to the number that was returned.

I know that the thread function works properly since I counted the number of lines in the text file with another piece of code. The problem arises when I use a loop to call `pthread_create` more than once. The `totalCount` I get from counting one file is accurate, but when I open two or more files, the `totalCount` in `main()` is wrong.

What might be going wrong in my program that's causing this? Is it a problem in my thread function? my `pthread_join`? I know this question might be pretty ambiguous without code but any thoughts at all given this description?

Comment: "I know this question might be pretty ambiguous without code but any thoughts at all given this description?"  Ambiguous indeed.  Seems you should post the code?

Comment: You've likely got a race condition or you're not properly guarding your shared resources.  I cannot tell you what the problem is without seeing your code.

Comment: You say you're creating more than one thread ? any chance you're overwriting the pthread_t with each new thread and thereby only join'ing the *last* one? Some code would make this a *LOT* easier, btw.

Answer (score 0):

W/o code is all speculation. But for sure `totalCount +=` is not thread safe. You need either an atomic interlocked operation (eg. [`__sync_fetch_and_add`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.0/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html)) or you need to protect it with a mutex.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a shot in the dark for the fun of it--the only way I could see this error happening is if the internal line counter--not `totalCount`, but rather what's keeping track of the number of lines in each file--is a global variable.  Each pthread is presumably calling the same line-counting function, so the line counts for each file will be incorrectly increased when the other thread updates.  So I'll predict that `totalCount` is always larger than, not smaller than, the actual number of lines.